# hotfix securing many log4j jars against log4shell

Tags: linux, log4j, log4shell

I have to secure some servers against CVE-2021-44228 aka [log4shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log4Shell). Those machines are running Linux and have a huge amount of log4j jars all over the place, some from app servers, some from legacy software, etc. I fear it is not possible to update all of them to the latest log4j.

However, if I understand correctly one can prevent log4shell in log4j 1.x by removing the impacted class like this:

```
zip -q -d log4j.jar org/apache/log4j/net/JMSAppender.class
```

And in log4j 2.x like this (see [logging.apache.org](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/security.html)):

```
zip -q -d log4j-core.jar org/apache/logging/log4j/core/lookup/JndiLookup.class
```

I think of a shell script to find all log4j jars, maybe like this:

```
find / -name "log4j*.jar"
```

and call those two zip commands on all results. Unfortunately I’m not good at shell scripting. Might anyone write a script based on this idea?

**Warnings:**

- Of course you loose all JNDI lookup and/or JMS functionality from
  log4j by doing so.
- log4j 1.x has other security issues. So it’s better to upgrade e.g. to latest logj 2.x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, here is my own shot at this. Not very elegant (quite repetitive), but with nicely colored output. And it only removes the class if the log4j version is compromised (FIX_VERSION="2.17.1" to also protect against [CVE-2021-45105](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2021-45105)) and [CVE-2021-44832](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2021-44832).

```sh
#!/bin/bash
echo " ┌──────────────────────────────────────────────┐"
echo " │ This is securelog4j version 1.5              │"
echo " │ https://stackoverflow.com/a/70362694/1948252 │"
echo " └──────────────────────────────────────────────┘"
preventLog4Shell() {
    readonly FIX_VERSION="2.17.1" # see https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/security.html
    readonly VERSION=$(unzip -p "$1" META-INF/MANIFEST.MF | grep Implementation-Version | cut -d " " -f2 | sed -r 's/\s*$//g')
    readonly RED="\033[31m"
    readonly GREEN="\033[32m"
    readonly YELLOW="\033[33m"
    readonly BOLD=$(tput bold)
    readonly RESET=$(tput sgr0)
    readonly SMALL=$(echo -e $VERSION'\n'$FIX_VERSION | sort -V | head -n1)
    if [ "$SMALL" = "$FIX_VERSION" ]
    then
        echo -e $BOLD$GREEN good version $VERSION:$RESET $1
    else
        hasJms=$(zip -v "$1" org/apache/log4j/net/JMSAppender.class | grep including)
        hasJndi=$(zip -v "$1" org/apache/logging/log4j/core/lookup/JndiLookup.class | grep including)
        if [ "$hasJms" ] || [ "$hasJndi" ]
        then
            if [ "$hasJms" ]
            then
                zip -d -q "$1" org/apache/log4j/net/JMSAppender.class
                hasJms=$(zip -v "$1" org/apache/log4j/net/JMSAppender.class | grep including)
                if [ "$hasJms" ]
                then
                    echo -e $BOLD$RED unable to secure:$RESET $1
                else
                    echo -e $BOLD$YELLOW secured:$RESET $1
                fi
            else 
                zip -d -q "$1" org/apache/logging/log4j/core/lookup/JndiLookup.class
                hasJndi=$(zip -v "$1" org/apache/logging/log4j/core/lookup/JndiLookup.class | grep including)
                if [ "$hasJndi" ]
                then
                    echo -e $BOLD$RED unable to secure:$RESET $1
                else
                    echo -e $BOLD$YELLOW secured:$RESET $1
                fi
            fi
            else echo -e $BOLD$GREEN found clean:$RESET $1
        fi
    fi
}

if command -v zip &> /dev/null
then 
    export -f preventLog4Shell
    find / -name "log4j*.jar" -exec bash -c 'preventLog4Shell "$0"' {} \;
else 
    echo You have to install “zip” first.
fi
```

Output looks like this:

[image]

Screenshot notes:

- Two files were already cleaned before, thus “found clean”.
- The last file was readonly, thus “unable to secure”.